# Changed suoders to an account that doesn't exist, what should I do

Tags: 12.04, sudo, adduser, visudo

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 with single user, let's call him user1.

I then created a new user, let's call him user2.

I wanted user2 to be the only user with sudo rights, so I removed all users from the sudoers file, and wanted to add user2 only (and root of course), but I entred the name incorrectly, let's say I gave user3 the sudo rights (a user that doesn't exist).

so now the only users in the system are user1 and user2, they don't have sudo rights, and I didn't enable the root account, is there anything I can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot your system using a live CD, chroot into it and change the sudoers file to include the correct user.

In the live system, open a terminal and enter the following commands (where *sdXY* is the partition you originally installed your Ubuntu to) to prepare for the chroot.

- `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`
- `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
- `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
- `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`

Then, `chroot` into the system.

- `sudo chroot /mnt`

Now, you can proceed to edit your `/etc/sudoers` any way you see fit, the recommended way would be using `visudo`.

After you are done, exit the chroot using `exit`. Then, reboot to your normal system, where the effects from the changed `/etc/sudoers` should be in effect.

Comment: Thank you sir, I tried what you said, and everything worked like a charm. You have literally saved my day. If you don't mind me asking, why is this possible (for security reasons shouldn't the sudoers file be locked ?), and what one can do to prevent an outsider from changing the file ?. and thank you again for your original answer.

Comment: The only way of preventing such modifications is running a fully encrypted system. Then, the encryption password is needed to edit any file on the partition.